# Exists an implementation of a Progress Wheel like progress bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I need to add a progress wheel with the functionality of a progress bar in my app. It means that the wheel must be fill only with the percentage of the content that has been loaded.

I'm searching on google but, not got required answer. Need some examples on it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. You should first try implementing the widget yourself and come back with that code if you have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

Taken from the `ProgressBar` documentation:

> If you will use the progress bar to show real progress, you must use the horizontal bar.

So you can't show progress in the progress wheel.